# Database Design - Using Short instead of Varchar - for Status Field

Tags: java, database, database-design, database-performance

The following approaches are possible for designing a status related fields in a DB table.

**Approach 01 :**

- Using 'VARCHAR' as a data type.
- The direct status will be stored like NEW, IN PROGRESS, CLOSED

**Limitations :**

- Search for string in a table always requires more time & resource
- Changing the existing status text (ex: 'closed' to 'completed') requires full table update

**Approach 02 :**

- Create a status look-up table
- Use the status table as a foreign key in the dependent tables

**Limitations :**

- Maintaining the foreign key relationships
- Need to use JOIN for all the related queries in application

**Approach 03 :**

- Use short (or) int for the status field
- Maintain the status text using ENUM in the application interfaces(EJB)

This will solve the limitation of previous approaches

**Limitations :**

- Need to map the integer to the relevant status (But still using a enum instead a text is a better approach)

I feel the third approach will be more efficient in terms of
* Faster DB indexing
* Faster Search due to short (or) int fields (instead of) varchar
* Of course less memory finger print

Could you please advise if there are any pit-falls of the third approach in terms of flexibility, maintenance and performance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Approach 02 :

Create a status look-up table
Use the status table as a foreign key in the dependent tables
Limitations :

Maintaining the foreign key relationships
Need to use JOIN for all the related queries in application
```

You only need to use a join if the value you store as a foreign key to the look-up table isn't human readable, or when only the full text is appropriate. If you use an integer, you'll always need a join. But you could use a human-readable code for some tables. And querying char(1) might be faster than an integer.  (None of these will be blazing fast if you have only three distinct values and 100 million rows.)

```
    status_code   status
    --
    N             New
    P             In progress
    C             Closed
```

Changing "Closed" to "Completed" would require updating only one row, but I'd consider that a coincidence.

```
Approach 03 :

Use short (or) int for the status field
Maintain the status text using ENUM in the application interfaces(EJB)
```

I'd hate to have to maintain a database that had nothing but integers for values.

If you're going to store an integer here, that integer needs to be a foreign key to a table that stores the values that are actually of interest to the business. And your application ENUM should be generated by querying that table, too.

Answer (score 2):

In our application we have used

> `[enum,VARCHAR(30)]`  for `PROCESS TYPES`

and

> `[String,VARCHAR(1)]`  for `PROCESS STATUS`

`enum` looks like to be a better choice as it saves `String` comparisons in Java code. 
So I believe if you choose the implementation to be a `[enum,NUMERIC]` field it should go all the way...

Answer (score 1):

In our project we used an approach very similar to your #3. At Java side we used `enum`s. We used JPA's [@Enumerated](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Enumerated.html)(EnumType.[Ordinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EnumType.html#ORDINAL)) to map enums to numbers when persisting to a database. We had the status text embedded into the enums (see an example below), but it could be completely separated as well.

**Pros:**

- Java code is much less error prone than working with just numbers or strings.
- The database part it's both space and CPU usage efficient.
- You can rename `enum` items  at will (but not rename or move, see the Cons part).

**Cons:**

- The numbers in the database are [ordinal numbers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#ordinal%28%29) of the enum. So you cannot remove or reorder `enum` items in Java code. You can only add new ones at the end of the list. It depends on your situation, but for us it wasn't a big deal. There is no reason for moving the order of enum items. And if we wanted to remove an item, we just renamed it to something like `REMOVED_STATUS_XY` to be sure wasn's not used in the code any more.

---

```
public enum Status {
    EXAMPLE_STATUS("User status message"),
    ... ;

    private Status(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
    private final String label;

    public final String label() {
        return label;
    }
}
```